# Error while creating rest API in postman 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I'm building an API using nodejs for the web I already have a database and the GET request works but when I try POST it gives me This error[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoxyc.png)

This is the code

```js
//user Schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        
    },
    profilePicture:{
        type:String,
        default:"",

    },

},{ timestamps:true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

This is the auth.js file for routing

```js
//auth route
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");



//Register
router.post("/register", async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password:req.body.password,

        });
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);
    }
    catch(err){

        res.status(500).json(err);

    }
});

module.exports = router
```

This is the main index.js file

```js
// index.js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const router = require("./routes/auth");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 

app.use(express.json());
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, ()=>{

    console.log("connected to a db server");

});

app.use("/api/auth", router);


app.listen("5000", ()=>{
    console.log("connected to port 5000.")
});
```

I see nothing at output but pair of empty curly braces. I have connected it to a mongodb cluster but i see nothing in the database aswell

Comment: I would suggest using a JavaScript framework, but aside from that, please throw your code into a code sandbox or online code editor and share that here since individual page code doesn't give us the entire picture.

Comment: This was my first question asked ever so sorry for some shortcomings. will take care next time

Answer (score 0):

try this on your index.js. after your DB is connected. you can start server

```
// index.js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const router = require("./routes/auth");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, () => {

    console.log("connected to a db server");
    app.use("/api/auth", router);


    app.listen("5000", () => {
        console.log("connected to port 5000.")
    });

});
```

Comment: nothing changed same error:/